# How to call a C library from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, c

I have a C library which I need to call from an ASP.NET / C# app, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

[DllImport]

Take a look at http://pinvoke.net/ - that should get you going! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

P/Invoke is your friend here, assuming you mean a true "raw" DLL, and not a COM object implemented in C.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a DLL, you can use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) to make function calls to it.