# Using "C" dll in C#

Tags: c#, c, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I call unmanaged C/C++ code from a C# ASP.NET webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720004/how-do-i-call-unmanaged-c-c-code-from-a-c-asp-net-webpage)

I have a dll file that is written in "C" language, i want to use it in C#. How can i do that?

Comment: This has been asked countless times already. Use the search function; you'll even find specific examples. [Calling C dll code from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916153/calling-c-dll-code-from-c), [How do I call unmanaged C/C++ code from a C# ASP.NET webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720004/how-do-i-call-unmanaged-c-c-code-from-a-c-asp-net-webpage), [How to call a C library from .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927569/how-to-call-a-c-library-from-net), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> Platform Invocation Services (PInvoke)
>   allows managed code to call unmanaged
>   functions that are implemented in a
>   DLL.

[Here](http://www.nag.co.uk/IndustryArticles/Calling_C_Library_DLLs_from_C_sharp.pdf) is a great tutorial by the NAG (Numerical Algorithms Group) group

Answer (score 2):

You can do a DllImport in your C# code and then use PInvoke.

For your custom dll you can try this [example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315051/using-a-class-defined-in-a-c-dll-in-c-code/315064#315064) on SO.

This a [good website](http://pinvoke.net/index.aspx) for reference for using windows dlls