# C source code to DLL for use in a C# application

Tags: c#, c, dll

I have a C source code written in VC++6.0 and I need that code to be used in a C# application which I am coding.

I have done few things to make that happen, I have run that C source file in release mode and have generated the intermediate.manifest file and the other files there, can I use any of these file to make my problem solved.

Comment: it's thousands of answers on SO. just look at related section. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941736/using-c-dll-in-c

Comment: The fact that you've posted a question here tells us that you'd like our help already, no need to say it again `;-)`

Comment: i really need help, if you can guide that will a great help

Comment: is it one C source file ? Is it not feasible to convert it to C#, or is there a specific reason that it must be C?

Comment: yeah it is just one C source file and including lots of header files, but i have them all

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is *import the dll* like this:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]//This is where you identify your dll...
   public static extern int MessageBoxA(  //This would be an object from your dll
      int h, string m, string c, int type);

   public static int Main() 
   {
      return MessageBoxA(0, "Hello World!", "My Message Box", 0);
   }
```

The keywords that you need to search on to learn about this are "running *unmanaged code*" and "*PInvoke*".

Comment: yeah i want to call the dll like that but how can i convert the c source file to a dll?

Comment: For that SO may not be right place. Please search the internet for how to make a c dll in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to wrap the C code in managed C++. Microsoft calls it C++/CLI. Anyways, you then compile an 'assembly' from that wrapper. An assembly is just a DLL that contains managed code. Then you can 'reference' (the managed equivalent of linking) that 'wrapper' from a fully managed C# application. 
So the dependency could look like this:

C -> Managed C++ -> C#

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable enough wrapping up c code in c++ you could easily make a dll by following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) microsoft guide.  It details how to go about creating a dll in C++.  If you need a more in-depth explanation though feel free to get back to me, and I will try and knock up a quick how-to.

Also let me know if you use a different IDE or environment and I can taylor the answer to suit your needs more precisely.

Might be later on today though as am pressed for time at the moment.